# array index in GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I am new to grails and I am trying to use a variable as an array index within GSP
but it is not working, is this doable in GSP?

```
<g:set var="counter" value="${0}"></g:set>
<td align="center">${arr[${counter}][1]?.toDouble()}</td>
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

The `${}` expression is used to [embed Groovy code in a GSP](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#GSPBasics), it's not used to refer to variable values:

```
<td align="center">${arr[counter][1]?.toDouble()}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the variable 'arr' as a map key in the controller then the GSP can refer to it, eg:

Controller:

```
def myAction() {
  [arr: [1,2,3,4,5]]
}
```